# "Like" query in adapter c#

Tags: c#, dataadapter

I have a data adapter that was created from my data set. i want to do this query:

`Select Body 
  WHERE Body Like '%@INPUTTEXT%'`.

how can i do it? i want the "@INPUTTEXT" to be a parameter but because of the "' " it's a simple text...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`WHERE BODY Like '%' + @inputtext + '%'`

Answer (score 6):

I've done this before to do what you're asking:

```
string cmdText = "select * from table where column like @INPUTTEXT";
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString);
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdText,conn);
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@INPUTTEXT", string.Format("%{0}%",INPUTTEXT)));
```

Answer (score 0):

or in Linq

```
dc.Body.where(a+> a.body.contains("InputText")).Select(a=>a.body).ToList();
```